# how to extract out data from a txt file which is seperated by |

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way to extract out data from a txt file which data is seperated by row and each column of data is seperaed by |

Here's an example

```
12|john bravo|123 kings street
15|marry jane|321 kings street
```

Previously i did it by separating using spaces like this

```
12 john kingstreet
15 marry kingstreet
```

But it poses a problem when I add a last name to the names/ add an address with spaces, ex: john bravo
So I decided to separate the column data using |

this is how I extract the data

```
struct PERSON{
   int id;
   string name;
   string address;
};

//extract
int main(){
   PERSON data[2];

   ifstream uFile("people.txt");
   int i = 0;
   while(uFile >> data[i].id >> data[i].name >> data[i].address){
    i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

So how do i extract if the columns are separated by | ??

Comment: i am also saving with | through the program,txt files helps me keep my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read into a `struct` , I'd overload `<<` and then parse the text as mentioned in one of the answer .

Something like this :

```
#include<sstream>
//...

struct PERSON{
   int id;
   std::string name;
   std::string address;

   friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, PERSON& p)
   {
     std::string s;
     std::getline(is, s); //Read Line, use '\r' if your file is saved on linux
     std::stringstream ss(s);
     std::getline(ss, s, '|');  //id
     p.id = std::atoi(s.c_str()); 
     std::getline(ss, p.name, '|'); // name
     std::getline(ss, p.address, '|'); //address

    return is ;
   }
};
```

And then you can probably do,

```
std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
PERSON p1;
while (fin >> p1)
   //std::cout << p1.id << p1.name << std::endl ;
```

You can overload `<<` too

Comment: when I add a new element to the struct PERSON, for example, i added `float cash` and for the getline, i added  `std::getline(ss, p.cash, '|');` , i got an error: no instance of overloaded function std::getline

Comment: @Ah, for `float` use [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), like shown `std::stoi` for `int`. Also first see the error message and and study the references/documents. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) works on `std::basic_string` only

Comment: so if i add float as the last element, i should add this after getting   the address: `std::getline(ss, s, '|');
  p.cash = stof(s.c_str());`

Answer (score 4):

Use getline() twice:
First, get each line use default seperator (new line); second, for each segment from first step, use '|' as seperator. "stringstream" class may be used to transfer data.

---

@edward The code below is modified from yours, and I think @P0W58 's answer is better.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const int length = 2;

struct PERSON
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string address;
};

//extract
int main()
{
    PERSON data[length];

    ifstream fin("people.txt");

    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        string segment;
        if (!getline(fin, segment))
            break;

        stringstream transporter;
        transporter << segment;

        string idString;
        getline(transporter, idString, '|');
        getline(transporter, data[i].name, '|');
        getline(transporter, data[i].address, '|');

        stringstream idStream;
        idStream << idString;

        idStream >> data[i].id;

        i++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<length; i++)
        cout << data[i].id << '+' << data[i].name << '+'\
            << data[i].address << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This, or something like it, is the right answer, as compared to the approach posted in the question which did not treat newlines as special at all, leading to a whole class of bugs if the input contains "the wrong number of fields."

Comment: istream& getline ( istream &is , string &str , char delim ); ignore third param if use default seperator. And this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777775/getline-not-working-with-fstream

Comment: im still not quite getting the whole picture of the getline since its a different method from what I usually do. can you provide me with a code example? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use boost::tokenizer or find first of like :

```
// code example
string s = "12|john bravo|123 kings street";
string delimiters = "|";
size_t current;
size_t next = -1;
do
{
  current = next + 1;
  next = s.find_first_of( delimiters, current );
  cout << s.substr( current, next - current ) << endl;
}
while (next != string::npos);
```

Comment: what does `next != string::npos` mean?

Comment: this means position return by find_first_of is not equal to no match